Messaging program wont exit() when told
I'm trying to create a messaging system in python where two computers running the same program can message each other back and forth. I've accomplished that and added that if I type 'back' it exits the program. The problem is that the 'back' command only works for the client side, on the server side it shows that 'back' was entered and it prints 'exiting' but it doesnt close the server, but is still listening to the client side even though it has already exited.
This is my code
import socket
import threading
import sys
import time

# Configuration
SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'  # Server IP address
SERVER_PORT = 12345        # Port to listen on / connect to
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

clients = []  # List to keep track of connected clients
client_socket = None  # To keep track of the current client's socket
shutdown_flag = threading.Event()  # Event to signal shutdown

def handle_client(conn_socket):
    global shutdown_flag
    while not shutdown_flag.is_set():
        try:
            message = conn_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode('utf-8')
            if message:
                if message.upper() == 'BACK':
                    print("Client requested shutdown.")
                    shutdown_flag.set()
                    broadcast("Server is shutting down.", conn_socket)
                    break
                print(f"Received: {message}")
                broadcast(message, conn_socket)
            else:
                break
        except:
            break
    remove(conn_socket)
    conn_socket.close()

def broadcast(message, sender_socket):
    for client in clients:
        if client != sender_socket:
            try:
                client.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            except:
                remove(client)

def remove(socket_to_remove):
    if socket_to_remove in clients:
        clients.remove(socket_to_remove)

def start_server():
    global shutdown_flag
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
    server.listen(5)
    print(f"Server started on {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")

    while not shutdown_flag.is_set():
        try:
            conn_socket, addr = server.accept()
            clients.append(conn_socket)
            print(f"Connection from {addr}")
            threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn_socket,)).start()
        except:
            if shutdown_flag.is_set():
                break

    # Clean up server
    server.close()
    print("Server shut down.")

def receive_messages():
    global client_socket, shutdown_flag
    while not shutdown_flag.is_set():
        try:
            message = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode('utf-8')
            if message:
                print(f"Message: {message}")
            else:
                break
        except:
            break
    shutdown_flag.set()  # Signal shutdown to the server
    client_socket.close()

def send_messages():
    global client_socket, shutdown_flag
    while not shutdown_flag.is_set():
        message = input()
        if message.upper() == 'BACK':
            print("Exiting...")
            shutdown_flag.set()
            client_socket.close()
            sys.exit()
        client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

def start_client():
    global client_socket
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

    threading.Thread(target=receive_messages).start()
    threading.Thread(target=send_messages).start()

def main():
    global client_socket
    try:
        # Attempt to connect to the server
        test_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        test_socket.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
        test_socket.close()
        print("Connected to the server. Running as client.")
        start_client()
    except (ConnectionRefusedError, socket.gaierror):
        print("Server not found. Starting server.")
        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_server)
        server_thread.start()
        # Wait a moment for the server to start up
        time.sleep(1)
        start_client()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I just need help figuring out how to make the 'back' command close the server, client and exit the program.
This is the output from the client side when the client types 'back' is typed: 
This is the output from the server side when the server types 'back' is typed: 
as seen here, it doesnt exit the program and the client can still send messages: 

Why would it "exit" if it receives "bsck"? It also looks as though you may have confused yourself over the way you're using threads

bsck was a mistake, i then entered 'back' and it printed exiting

Messaging program wont exit() when told
Your send_messages function seems to terminate prior to sending the "back" message to the server. You could try sending the message before terminating in the if clause. Try to swap the order like this:
def send_messages():
    global client_socket, shutdown_flag
    while not shutdown_flag.is_set():
        message = input()
        client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        if message.upper() == 'BACK':
            print("Exiting...")
            shutdown_flag.set()
            client_socket.close()
            sys.exit()

The shutdown flag will be set, but only for the client, if server and client do not originate from the same process.

thanks, that somewhat works, but if i type back on the client side it doesnt actually exit() the program for the server side.
